# xPath expression in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jexcelapi

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<include template="template.xml">
      <param name="view" value="exampleValue"/>
      <param name="table" value="exampleValue"/>
      <param name="title" value="exampleValue"/>
      <param name="addTitle" value="exampleValue"/>
      <param name="permission" value="exampleValue"/>
      <param name="icon" value="exampleValue"/>
    </include>
```

Now I want to check with xPath in my Java project if there is a `<include>`-node with a attribute called `template` and if the child nodes contain a `name`-attribute and the accompanying `value`.

I tried this:

```
String expression ="//include[@template]";                                                                          //Expression;
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);


for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
{
  String match = nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").toString();
  String match2 = nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("template").toString();
  System.out.println(match);
  System.out.println(match2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `/include[@template]/*[@name][@value]`

this will give you the nodes which contains name and value under include element/node.